# How do I properly format a request for ffmpeg to decode using a particular codec?

Tags: ffmpeg

r3d is listed as a supported codec for decoding, however when I attempt to specify the r3d decoder, I get the error message "Unknown decoder". What is the correct manner of specifying a decoder codec?

```
me$ ffmpeg -c r3d -i one.r3d one.mpg
ffmpeg version 1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May  8 2013 19:48:08 with Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/1.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=cc --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[mp3 @ 0x7fa2e4006600] Format mp3 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
Unknown decoder 'r3d'
```

Comment: Make sure r3d is a supported decoded in your specific build of ffmpeg using `ffmpeg -decoders`.  Also, googling shows there have been issues with decoding more recent versions of the R3D format. Example: http://www.cinematography.com/index.php?showtopic=53575

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that my version of ffmpeg was not compiled with r3d support, so while it did appear under

```
ffmpeg -formats
```

it did not appear under

```
ffmpeg -decoders
```

Comment: Its not a codec its a format. Its a container that uses JPEG2000 encoded frames and pcm audio.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `r3d` codec

```
$ ffmpeg -codecs -v warning | grep r3d | wc
      0       0       0
```